# What type of data packages am I looking for?

Tags: consumer-theory, data-request, research

I did a bit of googling and I see there are companies that sell market research data, and wanted to know if anyone knows more about it.

I am specifically looking for consumer interest in the allergic to foods category; for people who are allergic to certain foods, what is their interest in foods manufactured with their needs in mind.

Do you know of a company that has good data on the subject? I've come across a company, Epsilon, that says they can sell me data from surveys relating to what I'm interested in.

In passing the representative mentioned that although they are not the biggest company with the most amount of data regarding what I requested, they still have a large amount of data.

So I'm wondering which other companies are there out there that might have the date on this.

Comment: I came across this article on Forbes about consumer data. I will look into it: http://www.forbes.com/sites/metabrown/2015/09/30/when-and-where-to-buy-consumer-data-and-12-companies-who-sell-it/#54f45b18711b